# Remove part of word from a string with Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to find words in a sentence starting with a prefix and remove the rest of the characters.

Example:

*this sentence `Type_123` contains a `Type_uiy`*

I would like to remove the characters that come after **Type** so I can have:

*this sentence `Type` contains a `Type`*

I know how I would go to remove the prefix with regex  `str.replace(/Type_/g,'')` but how do I do the opposite action?

**N.B.** js prior ES6 if possible

Comment: `str = str.replace(/\b(Type)_\w+/g,'$1')`

Comment: Or `str.replace(/(?<=Type)\w+/g, '')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the expression `\b(Type)\w+` to capture the *Type* prefix.

Explanation:

```
\b     | Match a word boundary (beginning of word)
(Type) | Capture the word "Type"
\w+    | Match one or more word characters, including an underscore
```

```js
var str = 'this sentence Type_123 contains a Type_uiy';
var regex = /\b(Type)\w+/g;

console.log(str.replace(regex, '$1'));
```

The `$1` in the `replace()` method is a reference to the captured characters. In this case, `$1` stands for `Type`. So anywhere in the sentence, *Type_xxx* will be replaced with *Type*.

See MDN's [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) on the `replace()` method.

Comment: what is $1 for?

Comment: Adding a link for the `String.prototype.replace()` method's documentation(from the Mozilla Developers Network would be better) will help, not only the OP, but anyone who sees your answer.

Comment: I completely agree. I'll add it.

Comment: @Jonathan However, `\b(Type)\w+` will replace `Typer` with `Type`, too. If you need to make sure there is an underscore, add it explicitly as in `\b(Type)_\w+` , do not rely on `\w`.

Answer (score -1):

Install: https://github.com/icodeforlove/string-saw

```
let str = "Here's a sentence that contains Type_123 and Type_uiy";
let result = saw(str)
    .remove(/(?<=Type_)\w+/g)
    .toString();
```

The above would result in:

```
"Here's a sentence that contains Type_ and Type_"
```